# How to get OpenCV to display entire camera frame?

Tags: python, opencv, camera

I'm using a 180 degree FOV fisheye camera for a project and am having difficulty getting OpenCV to display the entire camera frame. When I open the camera in the standard Windows camera app it shows the full 180 degree FOV, but when I use a simple script to display the camera in Python it crops a decent chunk of the image and nearly halves the FOV.

Image using Windows camera app: https://ibb.co/WFK8Jm2

Image when Python script is running: https://ibb.co/QddnWXJ

Below is the code I'm using:

```
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)


if not cap.isOpened():
    raise IOError("Cannot open webcam")

while True:
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    frame = cv2.resize(frame, (1500,1000), fx=0, fy=0, interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA)
    cv2.imshow('Input', frame)

    c = cv2.waitKey(1)
    if c == 27:
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Anyone know how to stop this auto-cropping and display the full frame? Resizing the window doesn't help. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: why do you think "resizing the window" or a call to `cv2.resize` should help?

Answer (score 2):

Affter you defined your video capture, print these two variables:

```
print(cap.get(cv.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH), cap.get(cv.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT))
```

If it prints the default OpenCV values `640, 480`, then you can set them to your camera's resolution with the `cap.set` method:

```
cap.set(cv.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, camera_width)
cap.set(cv.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, camera_height)
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! It works fine now, it did the trick. Can't tell you how grateful I am.